# Can not transfer values in list between classes

Tags: c#, list, class

my problem is that i can't transfer values in the list between two classes in WFA

```
public partial class Example : Form
{
    public List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Example2().Show();
    }

    private void Example_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myList.Count == 0)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
}

public partial class Example2 : Form
{
    static Example ex = new Example();

    private void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ex.myList.Add("something");
        Close();
    }
```

Form "Example" is shown first. Then i click "Btn1" on the screen, and form "Example2" appears. When i click "Btn2" on "Example2" form, myList should get new value of "something" and "Example2" closes. But this part of script

```
private void Example_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myList.Count == 0)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
}
```

shows that myList has no values (myList.Count equals 0).
What can i do?

Comment: You don't have two, but three forms in your code. The first Example form creates a new Example2 form, which has another static new Example form. The two Example forms are different from each other. Their myLists are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reference existing Example form with data from Example2 form. `static Example ex` is another (static) instance, which doesn't have data.

```
public partial class Example : Form
{
    private List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var e2 = new Example2();
         e2.SetMainForm(this);
         e2.Show();
    }

    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
         myList.Add(item);
    }

    private void Example_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myList.Count == 0)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

```
public partial class Example2 : Form
{
    private Example ex;

    private void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ex.AddItem("something");
        Close();
    }

    public void SetMainForm(Example e1)
    {
         ex = e1;
    }
}
```